# DataViewGrid - selected rows (unbound)

Tags: vb.net

I can get the collection of selected rows but I cannot find a way to determine which is the first selected row. E.g. the table has 20 rows, the user selects rows 3,4,5,6 using the mouse on the rowheaders. How can I determine that the selection starts at row 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the rows by their index to put them in order.  A LINQ example that puts them in a list:

```
    Dim orderedList As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows Select row Order By row.Index).ToList
```